# Numbers of length N and value less than K

Tags: python, programming-challenge

I am solving interview question from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/numbers-of-length-n-and-value-less-than-k/).

> Problem : Given a set of digits (A) in sorted order, find how many numbers of length B are possible whose value is less than number C.
>
> Constraints: 1 ≤ B ≤ 9, 0 ≤ C ≤ 1e9 & 0 ≤ A[i] ≤ 9
>
> ```
> Input: A = [ 0 1 5], B=  1  , C = 2 ; Output:  2 (0 and 1 are possible)  
> Input: A = 0 1 2 5  , B =  2  , C = 21 ; Output: 5 (10, 11, 12, 15, 20 are possible)
> ```

This is my approach

```
from itertools import product
from itertools import ifilter
def solve(A, B, C):
    if A == [] or B > len(str(C)):
        return 0
       
    elif B < len(str(C)):
        #constraint is B
        if B == 1:
            new_list = A
            return len(new_list)
        else:
            new_list = list((product((''.join(str(i)for i in A)),repeat = B)))
            b = [''.join(num) for num in new_list]
            c = list(ifilter(lambda  x: x[0]!='0'  , b))
            return len(c)
                
            
    elif B == len(str(C)):
        #constraint is C 
        if B == 1:
            new_list = [i  for i in A if i< C]
            return len(new_list)
        else:
            new_list = list((product((''.join(str(i)for i in A)),repeat = B)))
            b = [''.join(num) for num in new_list]
            c = list(ifilter(lambda  x: x[0]!='0' and int(x) < C   , b))
            return len(c)
```

Test cases:

```
assert solve([2],5,51345) == 1
assert solve([],1,1) == 0
assert solve([ 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 ],5,42950) == 2592
assert solve([0],1,5) == 1
assert solve([0,1,2,5],1,123) == 4
assert solve([0,1,5],1,2) == 2
assert solve([ 3 ],5, 26110) == 0
assert solve([0,1,2,5],2,21) == 5
```

How can I optimize this code in terms of memory usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Optimise memory usage**

You could optimise memory usage by not converting your iterators into list and by avoiding non-required steps (like `join`).

Changing a few others details (formatting, adding tests, etc), you'd get something like:

```
from itertools import product
from itertools import ifilter

def solve(A, B, C):
    c_len = len(str(C))
    if A == [] or B > c_len:
        return 0
    elif B < c_len:
        # Constraint is B
        if B == 1:
            return len(A)
        else:
            candidates = product((str(i) for i in A), repeat = B)
            return sum(x[0] != '0' for x in candidates)
    else:
        assert B == c_len
        # Constraint is C
        if B == 1:
            return sum(i < C for i in A)
        else:
            candidates = product((str(i) for i in A), repeat = B)
            return sum(x[0] != '0' and int(''.join(x)) < C for x in candidates)

assert solve([2],5,51345) == 1
assert solve([],1,1) == 0
assert solve([2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9],4,42950) == 1296
assert solve([2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9],5,42950) == 2592
assert solve([0],1,5) == 1
assert solve([0,1,2,5],1,123) == 4
assert solve([0,1,5],1,2) == 2
assert solve([3],5, 26110) == 0
assert solve([0,1,2,5],2,21) == 5
```

**Another algorithm**

I'm pretty sure the whole thing can be optimised further by not generating the various numbers to count them but just using mathematical tricks to get the solution with no counting.

The easiest case to handle is `B < c_len`:

```
elif B < c_len:
    # All combinations of B elements are valid
    return len(set(A)) ** B
```

*Actually, as mentionned by Maarten Fabré, this does not handle 0s perfectly. The code below is updated to handle it better.*

The last case is trickier. We can try to use recursion to solve smaller versions of the problem. I didn't manage to make this work properly...

```
from itertools import product, ifilter, dropwhile, product, takewhile
import timeit

def solve_naive(A, B, C):
    A = set(str(A))
    mini = 10 ** (B-1)
    maxi = min(10 * mini, C)
    cand = [str(i) for i in (['0'] if B == 1 else []) + range(mini, maxi)]
    valid = [i for i in cand if all(c in A for c in i)]
    return len(valid)


def solve_op(A, B, C):
    # print(A, B, C)
    c_len = len(str(C))
    if A == [] or B > c_len:
        return 0
    elif B < c_len:
        # Constraint is B
        if B == 1:
            return len(A)
        else:
            candidates = product((str(i) for i in A), repeat = B)
            return sum(x[0] != '0' for x in candidates)
    else:
        assert B == c_len
        # Constraint is C
        if B == 1:
            return sum(i < C for i in A)
        else:
            candidates = product((str(i) for i in A), repeat = B)
            return sum(x[0] != '0' and int(''.join(x)) < C for x in candidates)


def solve_maarten(A, B, C):
    if A == [] or B > len(str(C)):
        return 0
    c_tuple = tuple(map(int, str(C)))
    combinations = product(A, repeat=B)
    if B != 1:
        combinations = dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] == 0, combinations)
    if B == len(c_tuple):
        combinations = takewhile(lambda x: x < c_tuple, combinations)
    combinations = list(combinations)
    return sum(1 for _ in combinations)


def solve(A, B, C):
    c_str = str(C)
    c_len = len(c_str)
    if A == [] or B > c_len:
        return 0
    if B < c_len:
        a_len = len(set(A))
        if B == 1:
            return a_len
        non_0_len = a_len - (0 in A)
        return non_0_len * (a_len ** (B-1))
    assert B == c_len    # Constraint is C
    head, tail = int(c_str[0]), c_str[1:]
    nb_first_dig_cand = sum(i < head for i in A)
    if not tail or not nb_first_dig_cand:
        return nb_first_dig_cand
    if head in A:  # TODO: This case is not handled properly...
        # It should involve ret and solve(A, B-1, int(tail)) or something like that
        return solve_maarten(A, B, C)
    solve_c = solve(A, B-1, C)
    ret = nb_first_dig_cand * solve_c
    return ret


tests = [
    ([2], 4, 51345, 1),
    ([2], 5, 51345, 1),
    ([], 1, 1, 0),
    ([2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9], 4, 42950, 1296),
    ([2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9], 5, 42950, 2592),
    ([0], 1, 5, 1),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 1, 123, 4),
    ([0, 1, 5], 1, 2, 2),
    ([3], 5, 26110, 0),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 1, 21, 4),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 2, 21, 5),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 2, 201, 12),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 3, 2010, 48),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 4, 20108, 192),
    ([0, 1, 2, 5], 5, 201089, 768),
    ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], 5, 201089, 28672),
    ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8], 6, 201089, 33344),
    ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], 6, 200000, 59049),
    ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], 6, 999999, 472391),
    ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], 6, 200000, 32768),
    ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], 6, 999999, 262143),
]
funcs = [solve, solve_op, solve_maarten, solve_naive]

for func in funcs:
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for (A, B, C, exp) in tests:
        ret = func(A, B, C)
        if ret != exp:
            print "%s(%s, %d, %d): ret=%d, exp:%d" % (func.__name__, str(A), B, C, ret, exp)
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    print("Time for %s: %f" % (func.__name__, end - start))




def solve2(A, B, C):
    c_str = str(C)
    c_len = len(c_str)
    if A == [] or B > c_len:
        return 0
    if B < c_len:
        a_len = len(set(A))
        if B == 1:
            return a_len
        non_0_len = a_len - (0 in A)
        return non_0_len * (a_len ** (B-1))
    assert B == c_len    # Constraint is C
    head, last_dig = divmod(C, 10)
    nb_last_dig_cand = sum(i < last_dig for i in A)
    if head == 0:
        return nb_last_dig_cand
    ret = solve_naive(A, B-1, head - 1) * len(A)
    ret_dummy = solve_naive(A, B, C)
    print(ret - ret_dummy, A, B, C)
    return ret_dummy
```

Comment: `if A == [] or B > c_len:` could be `if A or B > c_len:` (even if some newbies may think that it tests `> c_len` for both A & B :)

Comment: in the case of B < c_len,  and B > 1 you must discard the ones that start with a 0, or use `len(<A without 0>) * len(A)**(B-1)`

Comment: Oh, I guess I missed an edge case. Would you have a test case for this ?

Comment: For some reason, it passes just fine...

Comment: `solve([0,1,2,5],2,201) == 12`

Comment: @MaartenFabré Indeed. Thanks for spotting this. I've updated my answer (code and test suite).

Comment: shouldn't it be `( a_len-1) * a_len ** (B-1)`, and since A is ordered, `0 in A` can also be expressed as `not A[0]`, depending on which is faster

Comment: @TobySpeight  : I've understood the issue and fixed the code accordingly. Handling 0 as a number of length 1 is the whole trick...

Answer (score 5):

## DRY

The code you use for the special cases is independent from each other, and has no impact on the further handling of the data, so it is unnecessary to make a complete code path for each of the combinations edge cases, since this will explode the number of code quickly.

## generators

You seem to use iterators, but instantiate the list intermediately at every step, while this is not needed. Even counting how much items are in a iterator can be done more memory efficient with `sum(1 for _ in iterator)` instead of `len(list(iterator))`

## comparison

instead of converting all the combinations to `str` and then back to `int`, why not keep it in the shape of a tuple and use tuple comparison.

## Ordered

Since the list of digits is ordered, the products will be ordered too. So, instead of using `ifilter`, you can use `takewhile` and `dropwhile`, this will limit the number of checks to be done

## My code:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, product, takewhile

def solve(A, B, C):
    if A == [] or B > len(str(C)):
        return 0
    c_tuple = tuple(map(int, str(C)))
    combinations = product(A, repeat=B)
    if B != 1:
        combinations = dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] == 0, combinations)
    if B == len(c_tuple):
        combinations = takewhile(lambda x: x < c_tuple, combinations)
    return sum(1 for _ in combinations)
```

## alternative implementation

Since apparently this isn't fast enough, I was looking for another way around this, without generating all the possibilities:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def solve_fast(A, B, C):
    c_tuple = tuple(map(int, str(C)))
    if A == [] or B > len(c_tuple) or c_tuple[0] < A[0]:
        return 0
    if A == [0]:
        return B == 1 and C != 0
    if B == 1:
        return sum(1 for a in A if a < C)
    len_a, len_c = len(A), len(c_tuple)
    A_0 = not A[0]
    if B < len_c or c_tuple[0] > A[-1]:
        return len_a ** (B-A_0) * (len_a-A_0)**A_0

    idx_c = bisect_left(A, c_tuple[0]) - A_0
#     idx_c = sum(0 < a < c_tuple[0] for a in A)
    result_smaller = idx_c * len_a**(len_c - 1) 
    # number of combinations starting with a smaller digit that the first digit of C which is not 0,

    result_same = 0
    c_equal = c_tuple[0] in A
    for i, c in enumerate(c_tuple[1:], 2):
        if not c_equal: # as long as there is a digit in A which is the same as the next digit in C, continue
            break
        idx_c = bisect_left(A, c) # numbers of digits smaller than c
#         idx_c = sum(a < c for a in A) # numbers of digits smaller than c
        if A[idx_c] != c:
            c_equal = False
        if idx_c:
            result_same += idx_c * len_a ** (len_c - i)
    return result_same + result_smaller
```

This code is far less elegant than the other one, but it is faster.

If I look closer to it, it has the same backbone as josay's algorithm, but without the recursion, and converting `C` to a `tuple` of `int`s, instead of keeping it as a `str`.

### timings:

```
def test_function(func, tests):
    flag = True
    for test in tests:
        A, B, C, expected = test
        result = func(A, B, C)
        if expected != result:
            print(f'{func.__name__}: {test} failed: {result}')
            flag = False
    return flag
funcs = [solve_josay, solve_op, solve_maarten, solve_dummy, solve_fast]
all(test_function(func, tests) for func in funcs)
```

all passed

## timings:

```
import timeit
for func in funcs:
    global_dict={'func': func, 'tests': tests, 'test_function': test_function}
    time = timeit.timeit('test_function(func, tests)', globals=global_dict, number = 1000)
    print(func.__name__, time)

print(func.__name__, time)
```

> ```
> solve_josay 0.036541963709623815
> solve_op 4.350994605536243
> solve_maarten 0.7999383794617643
> solve_fast 0.03256370566714395
> solve_dummy 113.19599720861424
> ```

shows the performance is pretty close to Josay's, but 20+ times faster than my original attempt

Comment: It looks good. arguments shouldn't be upper case, though, should they?

Comment: they shouldn't, I just followed OP's signature

Comment: There might be some potential code review, then? You already have an excellent answer, BTW.

Comment: In this case the OP inherited the signature from an external source, so I found it more important to stay consistent with that, than change the signature

Comment: @MaartenFabrté thanks for the review but now the source says time limit exceeded , so it still need to be optimised .